# __float__ and __round__ in python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, porting

One of the changes between python 2 and 3 is that the latter delegates to `x.__round__([n])` the operation `round(x, n)`. In python 2, for my classes implementing `__round__` and `__float__`, when I call `round(x)`, `x.__float__` is called.

How can I know that `round(x)` (and not `float(x)`) was called to reroute the call appropriate in python 2 and obtain a python 3 like behaviour.

thanks

**Update:** I came up with an ugly hack. I am sure that:

- it can be improved.
- it will not always work.
- The ndigits parameter is not handled in python 2.
- it should not be used in production.

but it was interesting to build it anyway. Thanks for all the clarifications.

```
import dis
import sys
import inspect
import functools

#'CALL_FUNCTION', 'CALL_FUNCTION_VAR', 'CALL_FUNCTION_KW', 'CALL_FUNCTION_VAR_KW'
HUNGRY = (131, 140, 141, 142)

if sys.version < '3':
    def is_round(frame):
        """Disassemble a code object."""
        co = frame.f_code
        lasti = frame.f_lasti
        code = co.co_code
        i, n = 0, len(code)
        extended_arg = 0
        free = None
        codes = list()
        while i < n:
            c = code[i]
            op = ord(c)
            tmp = [op, ]
            i += 1
            if op >= dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT:
                oparg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i + 1]) * 256 + extended_arg
                extended_arg = 0
                i += 2
                if op == dis.EXTENDED_ARG:
                    extended_arg = oparg * long(65536)
                tmp.append(oparg)
                if op in dis.hasconst:
                    tmp.append(repr(co.co_consts[oparg]))
                elif op in dis.hasname:
                    tmp.append(co.co_names[oparg])
                elif op in dis.hasjrel:
                    tmp.append(repr(i + oparg)),
                elif op in dis.haslocal:
                    tmp.append(co.co_varnames[oparg])
                elif op in dis.hascompare:
                    tmp.append(dis.cmp_op[oparg])
                elif op in dis.hasfree:
                    if free is None:
                        free = co.co_cellvars + co.co_freevars
                    tmp.append(free[oparg])
                else:
                    tmp.append(None)
            else:
                tmp.append(None)
                tmp.append(None)

            codes.append(tmp)
            if i > lasti:
                break

        pending = 1
        for (opcode, arguments, param) in reversed(codes):
            pending -= 1
            if opcode in HUNGRY:
                pending += arguments + 1
            if not pending:
                seen = dict(frame.f_builtins)
                seen.update(frame.f_globals)
                seen.update(frame.f_locals)
                while param in seen:
                    param = seen[param]
                return param == round

    def round_check(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(self):
            if is_round(inspect.currentframe().f_back):
                return self.__round__()
            return func(self)
        return wrapped

else:

    def round_check(func):
        return func

class X():

    @round_check
    def __float__(self):
        return 1.0

    def __round__(self, ndigits=0):
        return 2.0

x = X()

r = round
f = float

assert round(x) == 2.0
assert float(x) == 1.0

assert r(x) == 2.0
assert f(x) == 1.0

assert round(float(x)) == 1.0
assert float(round(x)) == 2.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always redefine `round` to try `__round__` first. Unfortunately this isn't a `__future__` import, so I don't think there's much else you can do.

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def __round__(self, n=0): return 1.
...     def __float__(self): return 2.
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> round(x)
2.0
>>> float(x)
2.0
>>> old_round = round
>>> def round(x, n=0):
...     try:
...             return x.__round__(n)
...     except AttributeError:
...             return old_round(x)
... 
>>> 
>>> round(x)
1.0
>>> float(x)
2.0
>>>
```

---

Note that this is at least a [documented change](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins):

> The `round()` function rounding strategy and return type have changed.
>   Exact halfway cases are now rounded to the nearest even result instead
>   of away from zero. (For example, `round(2.5)` now returns `2` rather than
>   `3`.) `round(x[, n])()` now delegates to `x.__round__([n])` instead of always returning a float. It generally returns an integer when called
>   with a single argument and a value of the same type as `x` when called
>   with two arguments.

Comment: I also looked if it was available in __future__ first! The problem with your redefinition is of round is that I am building a library. So I do not control how round is going to be used. I was hopping that it was possible to introspect the stack and figure out if it was called from by round()

Comment: Oh lord, don't do that. It will be horribly fragile and buggy. What is the different behaviour you want to implement in `round`? That is, what would you like the value of `round(x)` to be?

Comment: Remember, in Python 2.x `round` always returns a float -- so you don't want your class to break that contract anyway!

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, you can not override what `round()` does. It does not **delegate** to `__float__`; it first calls `float()` (which in turn delegates to `__float__`), then does the rounding. There is therefore no point in knowing if `__float__` is called from `round()` or not, as it will do the rounding for you. You can't delegate it.

If you want to implement your own custom rounding in Python 2, you should implement a `custom_round()` method that does the custom rounding, and use that instead of `round()`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I know that round(x) (and not float(x)) was called to reroute the call appropriate in python 2 and obtain a python 3 like behaviour.

You don't need to. if `round(x)` calls your `__float__` method, it will round the returned `float`s using the normal logic for `float`s. You do not need to consider it in the `__float__` implementation; you should return the same thing regardless of the calling context. Everything else is the calling context's responsibility.

```
>>> class hax(object):
...   def __float__(self): return 2.6
...
>>> round(hax())
3.0
```

Comment: One reason to have a custom `round` is if you don't want to return a `float`. (For example, I always think `round` of floats should be an int.)

Comment: I want to implement my own __round__ (like I do in python 3) but when I do round(hax()) it calls __float__. Katrielalex gave a good example.

Comment: Sure, but that's a separate question. You can't tell whether `__float__` was called by `round` or by `float`, and shouldn't try, which was my point.